# Efficiently find which range a value belongs to

Tags: python

I have some datetime ranges associated with values. I imagine the problem would be same for other ranges, such as integers.

```py
ranges = [
    (datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 10, 30), 100),
    (datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 10, 30), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 0), 200),
    (datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 30), 150),
    ...
]
```

This list is sorted and contains no gaps or overlaps. The lower bound is inclusive, and the upper bound is exclusive.

For a given datetime, I'd like to find the value of the range it belongs to:

```py
def get_value_for_datetime(dt: datetime.datetime) -> int:
    ???
```

For example:

```py
>>> get_value_for_datetime(datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 10, 45)
>>> 200
```

My first thought was to look at the `bisect` module but it seems like there's nothing in here to help me with ranges and there's no way to provide a custom function for deciding to look to the left or the right, but maybe I'm missing something.

I'm also not averse to a numpy and/or pandas solution if it's significantly faster, and it's also possible to use a different structure for the `ranges` list if it helps.

Comment: The intervals can be of any length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bisection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) on the lower bounds and then check if the corresponding upper bound satisfies the condition `upper_bound > value`:

```py
import bisect

lb, ub, values = zip(*ranges)

def get_value_for_datetime(x):
    index = bisect.bisect_right(lb, x) - 1
    if index == -1 or ub[index] <= x:
        raise ValueError(x)
    return values[index]
```